# gunicorn when started using supervisor throws database error, works properly when manually started?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, pipenv

I have a simple flash website created and deployed in a server with Nginx as frontend and gunicorn as backend to run the python code. With this setup everything is working fine. However, if i run the server using supervisor module, I'm getting below error. I have ensured all the environment variables are accessible, they are placed in .bashrc under home directory.

Not sure what am missing. My python code is deployed in server inside a pipenv virtual environment. supervisor was started within the virtualenv only. Not sure if it has any relevance.

## error log with supervisor

> [2020-11-10 05:45:29,604] ERROR in app: Exception on /home [GET]
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py",
> line 1020, in **call**
> return self.registry[key] KeyError: 139749229659968
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 2447, in wsgi_app
> response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1821, in handle_user_exception
> reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py",
> line 39, in reraise
> raise value   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1936, in dispatch_request
> return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint   File "/home/anandraj/FlaskProject/Proj2/main/routes.py", line 12, in home
> posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).paginate(page=page,
> per_page=7)   File
> "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
> line 514, in **get**
> return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py",
> line 78, in **call**
> return self.registry()   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/*collections.py",
> line 1022, in **call**
> return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
> line 3300, in **call**
> return self.class*(**local_kw)   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
> line 138, in **init**
> bind = options.pop('bind', None) or db.engine   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
> line 943, in engine
> return self.get_engine()   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
> line 962, in get_engine
> return connector.get_engine()   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
> line 555, in get_engine
> options = self.get_options(sa_url, echo)   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
> line 570, in get_options
> self._sa.apply_driver_hacks(self._app, sa_url, options)   File "/home/anandraj/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject-tLcktdEC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
> line 883, in apply_driver_hacks
> if sa_url.drivername.startswith('mysql'): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'

**Supervisor config**

> ```
> cat /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf 
> [program:Proj2]
> directory=/home/<user>/FlaskProject
> command=/home/<user>/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskProject->tLcktdEC/bin/gunicorn -w 3 run:app
> user=<user>
> autostart=true
> autorestart=true
> stopasgroup=true
> killasgroup=true
> stderr_logfile=/var/log/flaskblog/Proj2Flask.err.log
> stdout_logfile=/var/log/flaskblog/Proj2Flask.out.log
> ```

**Error while querying DB**

```
~/FlaskProject/Proj2/main$ cat routes.py 
from flask import render_template, request, Blueprint
from Proj2.models import Post


main = Blueprint('main', __name__)


@main.route("/")
@main.route("/home")
def home():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=7)
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)


@main.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='Anandraj')
```

**How my app is initialized?**

```
~/FlaskProject/Proj2$ cat __init__.py 
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail
from Proj2.config import Config


db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_mgr = LoginManager()
login_mgr.login_view = 'users.login'
login_mgr.login_message_category = 'info'
mail = Mail()



def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_mgr.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)

    from Proj2.users.routes import users
    from Proj2.posts.routes import posts
    from Proj2.main.routes import main
    from Proj2.errors.handler import errors
    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(posts)
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.register_blueprint(errors)
    return app(FlaskProject)
```

Comment: did you check your environment setup correctly ?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please format your traceback and include how you're running your script and relevant parts of the code, particularly around line 12

Comment: Updated the info as requested. I double checked my code, the environment variables are part of .bashrc and they are accessible always.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your supervisor config file? My guess here is that it's related to your `PATH` definition...

EDIT (12/Nov): After seeing you're supervisor config file I noticed that you haven't set the environment path.

> A list of key/value pairs in the form KEY="val",KEY2="val2" that will be placed in the supervisord process’ environment (and as a result in all of its child process’ environments)

from: https://docs.red-dove.com/supervisor/configuration.html

Can you try adding this to your configuration file? This will define your `PATH` as "/usr/bin/" for the environment that runs your gunicorn. If that doesn't work, please try use the path from where your virtualenv is running.

```
environment=PATH="/usr/bin"
```

Comment: this also did not help :(